# Is the Raspberry Pi a good portable "on the go" media player for road trips?

Tags: kodi, media

I'm asking about either XBMC/Kodi or a C/Python media player software that utilizes omxplayer.

I have a dvd player in my car that supports HDMI out so I bought an Amazon firestick but if there's no wifi (and my phone isn't able to tether), the entire firestick is locked out. I can't even access media offline.

I plugged the raspberry pi zero w and kodi/raspbian works -- but I'm wondering if there is a way to switch out usb flash drives with movies to automount so I can play them using a game controller or IR remote..?

I don't need any RSS features or thumbnail extraction or scraping tools/fanarts/etc.. -- just a simple minimal gui with the option to auto-mount a usb drive.

I'm thinking of programming something using python and kivy/tkinter -- but I'd had to learn it. If there's a tv interface out there already - please do let me know. Or if there's a bare minimum kodi skin that won't freeze on me, that would be ideal.

Comment: Kodi in and of itself should be the solution to all your problems. Try all three Kodi-focussed Linux variants, too (LibreELEC, OSMC and XBian)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try kweb ? It is a specialised, extemely configurable kiosk browser with great omxplayer integration. A little bit of HTML and bash scripting should be enough to create your own media center on top of Raspbian.

Link [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=40860)